# @JsonIgnore in jackson is not running for property level

Tags: json, jackson

@JsonIgnore in jackson is working for Method level but not running for property level

I am having two tables named FebePlant and FebeOrg with FebePlant as parent of FebeOrg so FebePlant is having OneToMany relationship with FebeOrg and FebeOrg is having ManytoOne association with FebePlant and while consuming json of Febeplant Enity, i want to avoid the FebePlant json which is a property inside FebeOrg
So i tried be below code and it didn't worked

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="PLANT_ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private FebePlant febePlant;


but when i tried the annotation at method level it worked
@JsonIgnore
    public FebePlant getFebePlant() {
        return this.febePlant;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both should work, with Jackson versions 1.9 and above.

About the only guess I have is that if you are using a persistence framework perhaps it uses dynamically generated classes which do not copy annotations from fields. But that's just a guess.

Comment: I am using Jackson 1.9.13 version still i am facing issue and i am using OpenJpa as my persistence framework

Comment: Then I would probably try to isolate the issue so that first use POJOs as-is, outside of framework, and see if that works as expected. On the other hand, if the problem turns out to be related to OpenJpa, there isn't necessarily much you can do except note the problem.